# 404 page when collection not found with Promise.all in NodeJS (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use a `Promise.all()` and ask an URL in multiple Mongo collections.

I realized that some URLs are missing.

So I have a 404 page when it's the case. How to avoid that (typically, it's with the Annonce collection) ? What can I replace `Promise.all` with ?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../helpers/auth');
const router = express.Router();

require('../models/Car');
const Car = mongoose.model('cars');

require('../models/Caratio');
const Caratio = mongoose.model('caratios');

require('../models/User');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

require('../models/Annonce');
const Annonce = mongoose.model('annonces');

router.get('/app/:cars_getroute', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Promise.all([Car.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute }),
                Caratio.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute }),
                Annonce.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute })])
        .then(result => {
            let [cars, caratios, annonces] = result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by some URL are missing?

Comment: I don't find a `cars_getroute` with `Annonce.findOne` (that's because there isn't one, I don't want to absolutely find it)

Comment: If `Annonce.findOne` doesn't return a document then `annonces` variable would be null. I see no relation of getting 404.

Comment: That's the problem, after that I try to find `annonces.number` for example, and I have an error in my rendering because it's null.

Comment: You can replace `Promise.all` with [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 1):

As Rafi said, as soon as a single promise fails in `Promise.all`, it will be rejected.

You can replace `Promise.all` with [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), so that a rejected promise will not impact (or stop) the other promises.

> The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either resolved or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

Keep in mind that `Promise.allSettled` is fairly recent and is not supported by IE or Edge, and older versions of the other browsers.
[Compatibility table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_allsettled)

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. one alternative way is filtering your promises so that you only wait for resolved ones.

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3].map(toResultObject)).then((values) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
        if (!values[i].success) console.log("ERR: " + values[i].error);
        else console.log(values[i].result);
});
```

see [Avoiding-Promise-all-fail-fast-behavior](https://nmaggioni.xyz/2016/10/13/Avoiding-Promise-all-fail-fast-behavior/)

**NEW ANSWER**

```
router.get('/app/:cars_getroute', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const promises = [
        Car.findOne({
            cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute
        }),
        Caratio.findOne({
            cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute
        }),
        Annonce.findOne({
            cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute
        })
    ]

    let [cars, caratios, annonces] = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(e => null)))
})
```

But of course you should check each value for nullability.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I suspected that Promise.all wasn't the good way to do this

Comment: Do you knox by what can I replace Promise.all with ?

Comment: See my new answer.

Comment: Did you find it useful? let me know if it didn't so that I can help.

Comment: It didn't work because I simplified my question. In fact I have other variables and a rendering. And I have a rendering error.